# Inherit Variables from Parent Class

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to work out how to inherit variables from a parent class.

I have two classes (simplified but same principle):

```
class Database(object):

    def __init__(self, post, *args, **kwargs):
        self.post = post

        self.report()

    def report(self):
        #... obtain variables from post ...
        self.database_id = self.post['id']

        #... save data to database



class PDF(Database):

    def __init__(self, post,  *args, **kwargs):
        Database.__init__(self, post, *args, **kwargs)

       #... if i try to access self.database_id now, it returns an error ...
       print(self.database_id)
```

instantiating script:

```
        Database(request.POST)
        PDF(request.POST)
```

I have tried just instantiating CreatePDF, as i thought the `Database.__init__(self, post, *args, **kwargs)` line would the Database class, but this does not work either.

I am trying to find the most pythonic way to do inherit. I can obviously obtain self.database_id from the post dict passed to PDF(), however I do not see the point in doing this twice, if I can use inheritance.

Thanks

Comment: The code you posted (once you fix the naming problem - 'CreatePDF' vs 'PDF' - and the missing `args` and `kwargs` names in `PDF.__init__`) does NOT "returns an error" (at least not when it's passed a dict-like object with an "id" key set). If you hope a useful answer, please post a REAL mcve AND the full error message and traceback - oh and yes what "request.POST" is, too.  Note that there are some other obvious issues with your design but that's another question.

Comment: What's a `CreatePDF`?

Answer (score -3):

Use:

```
class PDF(Database):
    def __init__(self, post, *args, **kwargs):
        # Stuff
        super().__init__(post, *args, **kwargs)
```

The correct approach to instantiated an inherited class is to call super().**init**(args), which in this case calls Database.**init** because of method resolution order.

See http://amyboyle.ninja/Python-Inheritance

Comment: I would ask that the downvotes be reconsidered as there was an edit to the original question after I answered ... my answer *is* correct -- the problem was that the OP was not calling super()